# Ctrader - Cached data not available or corrupted

Tags: c#, .net

I create my own cBot in cTrader 4.8.30, or use standard cBots. Backtesting is worked as expected.

When I run optimization, I'm getting error message:

> Cached data not available or corrupted

[image: Cached data not available or corrupted]

I did Windows update, cTrader update, restarts, but error is still there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found how to resolve it, there is permissions issue
Need to change AccessRights.None to AccessRights.FullAccess

Change

```
[Robot(TimeZone = TimeZones.UTC, AccessRights = AccessRights.None)]
```

To

```
[Robot(TimeZone = TimeZones.UTC, AccessRights = AccessRights.FullAccess)]
```

and after change u need to approve the permissions by click some approval button